# Copy Resource File to Directory - VSTO - VB.NET

Tags: vsto, embedded-resource, excel-addins

I want to copy a Bitmap file from the Resources in my VSTO Excel Add-in project to a directory on the end user's hard drive.

I want to copy the MyResourceBitmapFile Bitmap file to the "C:\MyTempDir" directory. I receive the error "Conversion from 'Bitmap' to 'String' is not valid.'  I was prepared for this error message because I am aware that the first parameter, sourceFileName, in the Copy function is a string.  I present the code to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.

Any suggestions are welcome.

```
Dim DirName as String = "C:\MyTempDir"
Dim ResoureFile as System.Drawing.Bitmap
ResourceFile = My.Resources.MyResourceBitmapFile
System.IO.File.Copy(ResourceFile,DirName)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.